# Is there a function to 'autocomplete' a variable to a desired library?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set a variable to one I have in a library. Is there a command to do this?

I'm trying to make a simple time zone converter and I want to check the input variable, but I can only check the variables in the list from pytz so I want to 'autocomplete' the variable. can I do this?

```
import time
import pytz
country = input("enter country")

from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

fmt = "%H:%M %p"

now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print (now_utc.strftime(fmt))

from pytz import all_timezones
if country in all_timezones:
    country = #completed country in list 'all_timezones'
    timecountry = now_utc.astimezone(timezone(country))
    print (timecountry.strftime(fmt))
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'autocomplete.' It seems to me that you don't need anything more. `country` is the string you need to pass to `pytz.timezone()`, am I wrong? You do not need to reassign or complete it.

Comment: the function timezone() only works for timezones in the list 'all_timezones' such as 'Europe/Rome'. What if someone inputs just 'Rome'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are looking for is a way to match the user input to the strings in `all_timezones` and look for a valid timezone.

As far as I know, there is no built-in function that does it, you have to do it by yourself.

It's not an immediate task, as you may have multiple options (let say the user inputs just 'Europe') and you have to take this in consideration

A possible way to do is the following:

```
import datetime
import time
import pytz

country = input("Contry name: ")
now_utc = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('UTC'))

fmt = "%H:%M %p"

while True:
    possible_countries = [ac for ac in pytz.all_timezones if country in ac]
    if len(possible_countries) == 1:
        cc = possible_countries[0]
        timecountry = now_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone(cc))
        print(timecountry.strftime(fmt))
        break
    elif len(possible_countries) > 1:
        print("Multiple countries are possible, please rewrite the country name")
        for cs in possible_countries:
            print(cs)
        country = input("Contry name: ")
    else:
        print("No idea of the country, here are the possible choices")
        for cs in pytz.all_timezones:
            print(cs)
        country = input("Contry name: ")
```

With a list comprehension I look for all the strings in `all_timezones` which contains the user input. If there is just one, the script assumes that is the correct one and perform the task. Otherwise if there are multiple possibilites it prints them (one per row with the for loop, but you may just print the list so its shorter on the screen) and then asks the user to rewrite the country name. If there is no match, it just print all the possibilites. You may find it ugly to see on the command line, but you should get the idea and then improve it.

If you wish to check also for spelling errors in the user input... that is a lot more difficult.